# What's the attitude towards questions about decompiled code?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27438571/3636680) come up. They ask about decompiled/obfuscated code.

So what's the attitude on SO towards these questions?

- Are they allowed?
- Should they be closed?
- Can users get into legal trouble for helping someone with this?

Comment: "Can users get into legal trouble for helping someone with this?" Why should they? The _OP_ can get into trouble if they are not allowed to post that code for legal reasons, but I doubt a random user providing help can - although IANAL and if you want a definitive answer to this you should ask a lawyer, not random meta.SO users. Regarding the specific question, close it because it is crap, not because of the obfuscated code (nobody cares about that if the question is good). OP says "I have this and want to do some things, can I use regex?" - that's way too unclear and broad to be answerable.

Comment: What would you do if it was *your* code?  Do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

If you can answer it, answer it. Else, leave it alone.. The OP will get into trouble if the policies of his *company* (assuming he is working for one) don't allow him to post code. There is nothing that can be done from our side.

Are they allowed? --> Yes.. SO doesn't place any restrictions on the *behind the screen* affairs like (is it copied code / is it stolen / is this proprietary?).

Should they be closed? --> No, questions should be closed solely based on their quality. I wouldn't close a question even if it was *directly copied from some other site*.

Can users get into legal trouble for helping someone with this? --> No. Although the OP might get into trouble.