# Is it okay to decompile code to provide an answer?

Tags: discussion

I just answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39991007/4949005), where the OP asked about why something works the way it does. I answered by decompiling parts of the code and posted it in the answer to explain why it works as it does.

I've seen [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280087/whats-the-attitude-towards-questions-about-decompiled-code) here on META, but that's about the question, not the answer.

My questions are:

1. Am I allowed to post decompiled code from a library that I don't own in order to provide an answer?
2. Maybe off topic, but is it legal to spread code in this way? It's not being used, and is available for most developer to get. This is code from Microsofts MVC libraries.

I realize that the answer should work without the code (or just parts of it), but sometimes it might make things clearer to see the actual code.

Comment: It has been [open-sourced with an Apache license](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc).  So perhaps better to reference the source in your answer.  And of course you are not breaking any rules.

Comment: As mentioned, It's been open source for some time, so you didn't really have to decompile it. You could of simply looked at the raw source files

Comment: Licenses and copyright. Would be fun to break them ;-)

Comment: When you decompile a DLL you're not looking at actual written code but instead generated code from IL. This is what tools like DotPeek and Just Decompile are for. As it's not the actual source I d say there's nothing wrong with it. I believe it only becomes an issue you if you modify it, recompile it and sell it

Comment: It just depends on whether "okay" extends to doing technically illegal things that don't really have a victim. I'm okay with it.  Quoting a piece of machine code from a copyrighted work should be considered fair use, just like quoting something from a novel when you're writing an expository essay.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are allowed to post code from other sources on Stack Overflow, as long as

1. you provide proper attribution, and
2. there isn't some sort of copyright on that code that prohibits it.

It doesn't matter if it is the actual source code of a library, decompiled source code or an example from a blog or forum.

I agree with you the code provides additional value to the answer, so I'd doublecheck the terms of use of the Microsoft library. [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328244/4751173) seems to indicate that it falls under fair use, but neither that poster nor I is a lawyer.

Comment: This is partially incorrect. In Australia, we are not required to display any copyright notice. So it is better to request permission to use things before using them (regardless of whether you are providing attribution). Just because you say, "Jessica made this", doesn't mean you have the right to use or distribute it.

Comment: @Jase: this answer doesn't stipulate a "copyright notice", but rather simply "copyright". I.e. it correctly addresses your scenario, where copyright protection applies with or without a notice.

Answer (score -27):

Not allowing to decompile the program you have is obviously a violation of your own right over your own property. In most states where there is a constution, it violates the constitution, or at least its spirit.

Unfortunately, it doesn't mean that the actually applied law allows you to do that *in practice*. Thus, it seems we have to partially give up some of our rights to follow some tricky formulated, often unconstitutional paragraphs.

Comment: Your initial assertion that a binary executable you have on your computer is your own property is not necessarily something that's a given.  (Not that it's *false*, more that it's not obvious one way or another.)  Additionally, you do not have the inherent right to do anything with any piece of property that you own.  There are limitations of your rights over your own property across all types of property.

Comment: YANAL, clearly.

Comment: (Not that legal systems *shouldn't* provide the protections you're implying they do, but it seems clear that this answer is based more on personal philosophy than extant law.)

Comment: Just because you have the legal right to use or possess something does not mean that you have the legal right to share that thing. Consider an eBook for example; just because you bought the eBook doesn't mean that you can post its full text online.

Comment: Hey, my nation's constitution says nothing about ownership and a neighbouring nation with quite a big economy doesn't even have a constitution! :-p